# Twilio Alphanumeric Sender ID and multiple phone numbers

Tags: api, twilio

I have difficulties understanding the Twilio API.

It is specified that to send text messages with alphanumeric ID, you need to replace the "From" attribute with the text to be displayed. It works perfectly for me as I have bought only a single number. But it makes me wonder how Twilio selects the phone number to be used to send the text message if you are using an alphanumeric ID with multiple numbers attached to your account.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The message is not actually sent from a number. It's identifying sender *is* that string that you used. So the messages are not actually attached to any number. You can, in fact, release the number you have in Twilio and still send messages from an alphanumeric ID.

This highlights the drawbacks to an alphanumeric sender ID though. As the message never came from a real number, the receiver cannot respond to it.

So, don't worry about buying more numbers, they won't be a part of messages you send from alphanumeric IDs.

Comment: Okay! But I thought the pricing was depending on the country of the phone the message originated from. So it is actually not true? Buying a number is mostly useful to receive calls/messages then?

Comment: Pricing is dependent on the country (and sometimes phone network) that you're sending to, not from. Numbers are useful for receiving calls/messages, yes, but alphanumeric IDs won't work in every country either, so you may still need a number.

Comment: Okay, this is all very logic. I don't know why but the documentation confused me!